# Render Partial Help and Breakdown

Tags: mysql, variables, object, ruby-on-rails-4, rendering

When a person uses:

```
<%= render user.posts %>
```

what is happening behind the code that is tells it to search for the partial _post.html.erb and know to pass the a specified user inside the call?

I have seen many example where a partial is called from outside the index, such as:

```
<%= render partial: "posts", locals: {post: post} %>
```

But that is different from the example above

Answer (score 0):

`render user.posts` detects a model/s as a parameter, and searches for `/posts/_post.html.erb` partial, see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), section 3.4.5.

`render :partial => 'xxx/yyy'` searches `xxx/yyy` file in views path `app/views`, i.e. `app/views/xxx/yyy`, you can see in which places these views are searched by looking at your rails server console.

Comment: Can the same result given using  <%= render user.posts %> being displayed in a partial? For example, creating a partial within the users folder called _user_posts.html.erb. The reason I ask is because I was looking to customize this view a little differently than when the other associated models that use the same call ex: <%= render subscriber.posts %>. Was not sure if possible

Comment: it would be less confusing if you use `render :partial ... ` in this case.

Comment: The situation I am try to solve is lets say you have the _post.html.erb being called from both the user ' <%= render user.posts %>' and also a subscriber '<%= render subscriber.posts %>' Essentially they would see the same layout as it is calling upon the same partial within Posts. I am trying to design two different views based on where it is being rendered from. A user would see it formatted one way and the subscriber another. I would guess in order to achieve this, I would need to create two separate partials. I am just not sure how to pass the information.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I was trying to achieve. I knew I was missing some simple.

Inside my show view:

```
<% @user.posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```